# Tell Excel to parse cells with units of measurement as numbers, including multiplier

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have some Excel files containing cells with values like "20 mA", "3.13 µA" , "1.66 mV" and similar.

Would it be possible to somehow ignore the last character ('A' or 'V') and then multiply the number with the suffix automatically?

For example 20 mA should result in 0.02

Comment: Are they all the same structure - so number followed by space, followed by a two character unit with the multiplier as the first unit?  Are they all either micro or milli?

Comment: if you want the cells identified and replaced then this is really a VBA question

Comment: @Paul yeah they are same format, actually there are multiple columns and each column is either 'A' or 'V' as for current and voltage.

Comment: @brettdj I dont want the numbers be replaces, just when I do for example a SUM, I want the sum to calculate the real numbers.

Comment: what I meant was if you have data in A1 that you want updated in A1 then this is best done with code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this kind of formula (if your formula is in `A1`):

```
=CONVERT(VALUE(MID(A1,1,FIND(" ",A1))), MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1)), LEFT(A1,1))
```

**Caveats:**

- Will work for the [supported units](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/convert-function-HP010062311.aspx) of the `CONVERT` formula
- Will work for the [supported prefixes](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/convert-function-HP010062311.aspx) (e.g. `u` for micro `µ`)

Comment: Is `CNUM()` the same thing as `VALUE()` in the American version of Excel?

Comment: +1 nicely done with a formula that is far too under utilised.

Comment: @Excellll: yes it is, sorry, I missed this part of the "formula translation". I will edit my post

Comment: nice solution. but seems only for excel 2007+